# ios Swift 2 read and return item in CSV file Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, csv, barcode

Sorry in advance that my Swift 2 Knowledge is extremely basic.
I'm trying to replace the string returned from barcode scanner foundCode(code: String) with its counterpart in a loaded CSV file at header (default_code) and return it to a UItextField in another viewcontroller.

I can successfully scan and segue with the original string but the output of aRow prints the entire CSV file as such;

```
Segue!
"Barcode Found: 9312311903002
["code": "code", "default_code": "default_code"]
["code": "9310097003060", "default_code": "1A1ALG"]
["code": "9310097003121", "default_code": "1A1ASG"]
["code": "9310097390801", "default_code": "1A1BS"]
["code": "9310097390702", "default_code": "1A1BU"]
......."
```

My function is as follows:

```
func foundCode(code: String) {
    print("Barcode Found: \(code)")


var myCSVContents = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

    CSVScanner.runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(["code", "default_code"], withFileName: "products", withFunction: {

        (aRow:Dictionary<String, String>) in

        myCSVContents.append(aRow)

        print (aRow)

    })


    self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(code)


    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Could somebody please assist me on how to get a single item with (code) and return (default_code) in the array?

Answer (score 0):

did you want like this ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let array = [  ["code": "9310097003060", "default_code": "1A1ALG"],
        ["code": "9310097003121", "default_code": "1A1ASG"],
        ["code": "9310097390801", "default_code": "1A1BS"],
        ["code": "9310097390702", "default_code": "1A1BU"] ]

    let str = "9310097003060"


    let defaultcode = getDefaultCode(array, code: str)
    print(defaultcode)

}


func getDefaultCode(array:[Dictionary<String,String>] , code:String) -> String?{
    let array2 =  array.filter({$0["code"] == code})

    return array2.last?["default_code"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get a Use of local variable 'getDefaultCode' before declaration error. How do I implement your example?

Comment: getDefaultCode is a func just put it outside your func

Comment: Oh that totally put your answer in perspective. Thank you!